# elastic Search with Play framework

Tags: elasticsearch, playframework

Is there any good example/reference for integrating elastic search with Playframework with Java

I tried the sample in https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch
but it gives the following error while I run the example

```
 sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.clever-age#play2-elasticsearch;2.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

and hence the compilation fails for references of import com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexResults;

Is there any other way to integrate elastic search with PLAY framework

Also i tried using
 "com.clever-age" % "play2-elasticsearch" % "0.8.1"

But hits the error :
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.6.2: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working with elastic from Play on scala. There is also no good integration.

I think that the reason is a very good elastic API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html

So you can easily create short methods that will wrap the functional your need. And you will get experience to work exactly with elastic, so you can use it later with any other technology.

Just use the REST API of an elastic server, in PLAY it's as easy as any "integration" middleware.

Another reason - elastic changes often, so it's a lot of efforts to support all changes in the "integration" middleware. You can see it from the repository in your post - a lot of releases just "to stay".

Comment: Thanks . Do you have any reference example.I am relatively new to play framewrok.Also I came across Java Client API (libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "5.0.0-alpha5")
and Java Rest Client ...Is it a good idea to use the same

Comment: I have not java example, I can advise you to read this docs: 

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS

That you must be able to do API requests to the elastic API with WSClient. 

And you do not  need `libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "5.0.0-alpha5"`